# How can I change node property value within input?

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, treenode

As you can see in screenshot I am trying to display node.name and node.value. The node.value is displayed in `<input>`, so if I want to change it. But when I write something in input field, the original data which is located in `dataSource.data` doesn't change - stays as it was. Obviously there is no two way binding, but how to implement it?

I have tried to go with `([ngModel])="node.value"`, but that didn't work.

```
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">
<mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodePadding matTreeNodeToggle>
<button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
<div class="col-l-4 col-m-4 col-s-4">
{{node.name}}
<span class="required" *ngIf="node.mandatory === 1">*</span>
</div>
<div class="col-l-8 col-m-8 col-s-8">
<input [type]="node.base_Type" class="form-input" [value]='node.value'>
</div>
</mat-tree-node>
<mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild" matTreeNodePadding>
<button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle
[attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.name">
<mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
{{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
</mat-icon>
</button>
<strong>{{node.name}}</strong>
</mat-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

So i would like, when on the end I will extract data from `dataSource.data`, that property values of nodes which were changed to be there changed, not original.

Comment: I think you've missed attaching the screenshot

Comment: yes sorry, no screenshot, just code

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz for the same?

Comment: yes, here it is https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-tree-dlsqfn